# TFS Rollback for non-consecutive chagesets

Tags: version-control, tfs

Is it possible to rollback multiple non-consecutive change sets in TFS. I know there is option for consecutive changes but for non-consecutive?

I am using TFS 2012

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rollback each changeset separately into your local workspace, but then do one-check-in with all the rollbacks.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I've just tried to do just that, but if a second changeset contains another rolled back file again (consecutive even), it complains that there are incompatible pending changes. Might just be my situation though.